# Reordering fields in nested dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

How do I reorder fields in a nested dataframe in scala?
for e.g below is the expected and desired schemas

````
currently->

root
 |-- domain: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- assigned: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- core: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- createdBy: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Event: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- action: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- eventid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dqid: string (nullable = true)

expected->

 root
 |-- domain: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- core: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- assigned: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- createdBy: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Event: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- dqid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- eventid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- action: string (nullable = true)
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `schema` before you read the dataframe.

```
val schema = val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("root",StructType(Array(StructField("domain",StructType(Array(StructField("core",StringType,true), StructField("assigned",StringType,true), StructField("createdBy",StringType,true))),true), StructField("Event",StructType(Array(StructField("dqid",StringType,true), StructField("eventid",StringType,true), StructField("action",StringType,true))),true))),true)))
```

Now, you can apply this schema while reading your file.

```
val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json("path/to/json")
```

Should work with any nested data.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient approach might be to just `select` the nested elements and wrap in a couple of `struct`s, as shown below:

```
case class Domain(assigned: String, core: String, createdBy: Long)
case class Event(action: String, eventid: String, dqid: String)

val df = Seq(
  (Domain("a", "b", 1L), Event("c", "d", "e")),
  (Domain("f", "g", 2L), Event("h", "i", "j"))
).toDF("domain", "event")

val df2 = df.select(
  struct($"domain.core", $"domain.assigned", $"domain.createdBy").as("domain"),
  struct($"event.dqid", $"event.action", $"event.eventid").as("event")
)

df2.printSchema
// root
//  |-- domain: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- core: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- assigned: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- createdBy: long (nullable = true)
//  |-- event: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- dqid: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- action: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- eventid: string (nullable = true)
```

An alternative would be to apply row-wise `map`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val df2 = df.map{ case Row(Row(as: String, co: String, cr: Long), Row(ac: String, ev: String, dq: String)) =>
  ((co, as, cr), (dq, ac, ev))
}.toDF("domain", "event")
```